# Expected behavior when sprintf to a null char string

Tags: c++, null, printf

While review code I found that the following code snippet.

```
sprintf(retValue, "%s", "");
```

I noticed this didn't cause a crash even when retValue was NULL.  I am beginning a rather large rewrite and if this way of setting a value to a null string is expected behavior I would prefer not to change it (though my heart tells me I should).

Comment: `sprintf` is never *guaranteed* to cause a crash, but it may invoke *undefined behavior*

Comment: Not crashing is an acceptable result of undefined behavior, as would anything else you might observe.

Comment: sprintf allows NULL for retValue.  The value returns by sprintf is the number of characters that would have been written to the buffer, had a buffer been provided.  (That count does not include the additional nul `'\0'` terminator, which is also written.)

Comment: Even if it isn't UB it seems to be a very verbose and expensive way of doing `retValue[0] = '\0';`

Comment: @Eljay I believe you may be confusing `sprintf` with `snprintf`, the latter being mentioned on cppreference as being usable for determining the necessary size of the buffer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: In cases like this one should apply the second rule of Ninjitsu: Expect the unexpected.

Comment: Since this is C++ the real solution is to use `std::string` and stay far, far away from C-style character buffers and the overflow problems that constantly plague them.

Comment: @UnholySheep • the `man sprintf` page I read said the same of sprintf, but that could very well be something that isn't portable.  I haven't used the various printf functions in a very long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Expected behavior when sprintf to a null char string

There is no expected behaviour in this case. The behaviour is undefined.

> I would prefer not to change it (though my heart tells me I should).

You should change it.

Comment: I am just getting back into writing C++ and was hoping their was something better.  I ended up checking for null before use.